# Simple Harmonic Motion, Given Speed, Acceleration and Displacement

Tags: trigonometry

I was studying for some quizzes when I stumbled on this quesion.
It goes like this:

> A particle moves with simple harmonic motion in a straight line. 
>   When t= 0, the acceleration is 4 feet per second per second, the
>   velocity is -2 feet per second, and the displacement is s = -1 foot.
>   Find the amplitude and period of the motion.

My work:

I do know that the differential equation that describe a
 simple harmonic motion is:

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + b^2 x = 0, $$

where  $b = \sqrt{\frac{kg}{W}}$

The general solution of the differential equation above is:
$$x = A \sin bt + B \cos bt$$
$$x = A' \sin (bt + B')$$

where $A' = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2}$ and $B' = \cos^{-1} \left (\frac{A}{A'}\right ) = \sin^{-1} \left (\frac{B}{A'}\right ) $

My problem is, even if I know the given, I don't know how to plug in the given values
to the differential equation or its general solution.....

I'm stuck.

How will you find the amplitude and period of the motion described in the problem?

Comment: plugging initial conditions for acceleration and position in the original DE gives $4+b^2(-1)=0$ so $b^2=4$ and the period must be $\pi$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the second form for the displacement as a function of time 
$$x=A'\sin(bt+B')$$ The velocity is then $$v=A'b\cos(bt+B')$$ and the acceleration is $$a=-A'b^2\sin(bt+B')$$ The ratio of acceleration to displacement is $$\frac{a}{x}=-b^2$$ $b$ is also related to the period $T$ by $$b=2\pi T$$
Once you know $b$, multiply the displacement by it, square both $xb$ and $v$. When you add them together you get $$x^2b^2+v^2=A'^2b^2$$ You can then get the amplitude